# can there be a divs method in PageObject::Accessors and is my workaround ok?

Tags: page-object-gem

In page object I would like to have access to multiple divs in a particular way.

This is access to the first div that matches:

```
div(:search_result, id: /rptSearchResults/)
```

This would be access to multiple divs that match if divs existed in PageObject::Accessors:

```
divs(:search_result, id: /rptSearchResults/)
```

So far I have tried:

```
visit_page SearchResultsPage do |page|

    #This outputs the first div that matches
    page.search_result_element.div_elements(id: /rptSearchResults/).each { |i| puts i.text }

    #This accesses the page and outputs text in all divs that match
    page.div_elements(id: /rptSearchResults/).each { |i| puts i.text}

end
```

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this within page-object?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: There was an issue opened for this recently - see [Issue 144](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/144)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the way you defined multiple divs, `divs(:search_result, id: /rptSearchResults/)`, you can access the elements by `search_result_elements`.

Some examples:

- Get the first div element - `search_result_elements[0]`
- Get the length of elements returned - `search_result_elements.length`
- Get the texts of the divs - `search_result_elements.map(&:text)`
- Get a child element from the third div - `search_result_elements[2].element`

Hope this helps!